# Обработка исключения InvalidConstraintException

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, исключения, datagrid

У меня есть `DataGrid` с `DataTable` на нем. Ограничения внешних ключей создаются в коде, `DeleteRule` установлен `None`. Я хочу, чтобы при попытке удаления записи из таблицы с первичным ключом, пользователю выводилось сообщение об ошибке. Программа вылетает с исключением InvalidConstraintException, но я не могу понять, в каком именно месте его нужно обработать?
Запись удаляется по нажатию кнопки Del в `DataGrid`.

Так я создаю ограничения для таблиц
    private void CreateConstraint(DataSet dataSet,
        string table1, string table2, string column1, string column2)
            {
                DataColumn parentColumn;
                DataColumn childColumn;
                ForeignKeyConstraint foreignKeyConstraint;

```
            parentColumn = dataSet.Tables[table1].Columns[column1];
            childColumn = dataSet.Tables[table2].Columns[column2];
            foreignKeyConstraint = new ForeignKeyConstraint
               ("SupplierForeignKeyConstraint" + table1, parentColumn, childColumn)
            {
                DeleteRule = Rule.None,
                UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade,
                AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade
            };

            dataSet.Tables[table2].Constraints.Add(foreignKeyConstraint);
            dataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
        }
```

[image: Вот скрин с исключением]

Comment: Это зависит от того, какое у вас исключение, в каком месте вылетает и как вы его хотите обработать. Короче, код показывайте.

Comment: неужто вам среда разработки не показывает на какой строке какое именно исключение??

Comment: исключение Invalid Constraint Exception. Нет, среда не показывает

Comment: Сейчас добавлю код

Comment: В обработчике кнопки на удаление проверяйте зависимость и если она есть, то выводите сообщение об ошибке и не запускайте удаление.

Comment: @Jagailo удаление по нажатию Delete. Я пробовала создать обработчик для  DataGrid KeyDown, но ничего не вышло